# Want to avoid eval AND Function constructor

Tags: javascript, function, eval

Trying hard to replace the eval without using Function constructor.  Stumped. I am not a newbie but not an expert either.

jslint says this is evil; when I replaced it with a Function constructor, it said that was just a form of eval()!

```
   evaluateEventScript: function(requestObject) {
        var resultData;
        resultData = eval(requestObject.script);
        //send resultData elsewhere...
   }
```

Help??

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Please clarify what your question is.

Comment: what is in `requestObject.script`? I'm assuming a block of JavaScript to execute, but is it a function, the result of an AJAX request, etc etc?

Comment: At this juncture I am not certain of the details of the JS code inside requestObject.script.  Very likely it is some JSON since that is commonly used in this code (that I just inherited).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you simply pass a function object in your scenario? 
e.g

```
var c = function(){
   ...
}


var evaluateEventScript = function(requestObject) {
    var resultData;
    resultData = requestObject();
    //send resultData elsewhere...
}

evaluateEventScript(c);
```

Or something in this form? this can work without eval or Function constructor. but it requires the requestObject to be a function object, and not a String.

Comment: > "then eval is your first bet..."  OK so sometimes it is OK to just ignore jslint's advice that eval is evil?  Many websites go so far as to say "there is nearly ALWAYS a way to avoid eval, and you should" but then they do not explain how.  Maybe it is time to invest in a good JS book rather than googling for answers.  This forum is really cool though -- I am looking for questions I can answer as well, to give back.

Comment: I will check to see if I can use a closure here instead, as you suggest.  I would still be interested in what the prescribed techniques are if I just want to replace the eval with the context I have supplied.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Dave correction, eval is always evil. you are right, edited the answer.